# howto configure mod_proxy for apache2, jetty

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, jetty

This is how I have setup my environment, atm. An apache2 instance on port 80. Jetty instance on the same server, on port 8090.

**Use-Case:**

- When I visit foo.com, I should see the webapp, which is hosted on jetty, port 8090.
- If I put foo.com/blog, I should see the wordpress blog, which is hosted on apache. (I read howtos on the web, and installed it using AMP.)

Below are my various configuration files:

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf:*

```
ProxyPass / http://foo.com:8090/   << this is the jetty server

ProxyPass /blog http://foo.com/blog

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyStatus On
```

*/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:*

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

I have not created any other files, in sites-available or sites-enabled.

**Current situation:**

- If I goto foo.com, I see the webapp.
- If I goto foo.com/blog, I see a

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /errors/404.html.
>   Reason:
>
> NOT_FOUND
>   powered by jetty://

- If I comment out the first ProxyPass line, then on foo.com, I only see the homepage, without CSS applied, ie, only text..
- .. and going to foo.com/blog gives me a this error:

> The proxy server received an invalid
>   response from an upstream server.
>
> The proxy server could not handle the
>   request GET /blog.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote
>   server

- I also cannot access /phpmyadmin, giving the same 404 NOT_FOUND error as above.

I am running Debian squeeze on an Amazon EC2 Instance.

**Question:** Where am I going wrong? What changes should I make in the proxy.conf (or another conf files) to be able to visit the blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to replace this line

```
ProxyPass /blog http://foo.com/blog
```

with this line

```
ProxyPass /blog/ !
```

This instructs the apache2 server to not to proxy anything that starts with /blog which is I think is what your want.

UPDATE: The official docs is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: **1.** That doesnt work. It still forwards it to jetty. **2.** Do u have any list or website, where I can see various types of proxypass

Comment: **EDIT:** I changed the order of the ProxyPass, and put the **/** at the end. Now it works. I guess it would just pass through. Thanks for the answer, I had lost all hope, people like you keep the love alive! Happy new year :)

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome. Fixed I updated my answer accordingly.